# Code works the 1st time, but not the 2nd time

Tags: excel, vba

This code just works on the first time because when It's activated again, It'll try to sum a function, not the value from this function.

For example: on first try the user enters with 100 on `J" & lrTest - 1` and G6 = 0. Then it'll be `=sum (0, 100)`, which is equal 100. But on the second try, it'll try to sum the function and won't go on.

```
If cmbcategoria.Text = "Casa" Then
    Range ("G6").Formula = "=sum ("G6", J" & lrTest - 1 &")"
End If
```

What can I do to solve it?

Ps: I guess you don't know the full code, but if needed, I can post it.

[This is how my workbook looks by now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN2zK.png)

Comment: You cannot put a formula into G6 that references G6. This is known as a [Circular Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-fix-a-circular-reference-C17488E3-3CBE-4FA8-A6BC-1A6FFA64DB78). Additionally, `"G6"` should be `G6` and you need to double-up quotes inside a quoted string. So basically, there is a lot wrong with the whole thing.

Comment: I dont think you have enough " around the g6 either.

Comment: I am not sure what your are trying to achieve, because I really didn't understand your question. But looking at the code that you have pasted(not considering the wrong cell references that are given) G6 should be the text i.e there should be no double quotes around it. your actual statement will become "=sum (G6, J" & lrTest - 1 &")"

Comment: I was able to run it when I used this `Range("G6").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("G6").Value & ", J" & lrTest - 1 & ")" `
It is on [ExcelForum's post](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1122181-code-works-the-1st-time-but-not-the-2nd-time.html)
But thank you anyway!!

Comment: why don't you try debugging and resolve each problem which gets highlighted....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work =)

```
If cmbcategoria.Text = "Casa" Then
    Range("G6").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("G6").Value & ", J" & lrTest - 1 & ")"
End If
```